# Find positions of given characters

Tags: perl, string

I want to find positions of some characters in order to process them without using monstrous recursive and inefficient regular expression. Here is how I do it:

```
my @charpos=();
s/(?=([«»\n]))/push @charpos, [$1, 0+($-[0])]; "";/ge;
# sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @charpos;
```

But this solution uses «substitute» operator to substitute with empty string, is this normal? Should the commented line be uncommented?

Comment: It's funny but, to me, that looks like a monstrous and inefficient regular expression.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Obtain a list of the positions (character offset) at which the guillemets and newline(s) appear in the string?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I want to replace `«...«...»...«...»...»` with `«...„...“...„...“...»`, but with some exceptions: if level1 closing guillemet is absent, then it should be left as is, same if level1 closing guillement is not present on the current line.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Trying to do this with regular expression caused me to write very long and inefficient one, so I switched to a list of positions like you have described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your general problem, you might want to examine [`sub parse_line`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CHORNY/Text-ParseWords-3.27/ParseWords.pm) in [Text::ParseWords](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aParseWords).

In the context of the code you gave in your question, I would avoid modifying the source string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict; use warnings;

my $x = q{«...«...»...«...»...»};

my @pos;

while ( $x =~ /([«»\n])/g ) {
    push @pos, $-[1];
}

use YAML;
print Dump \@pos;
```

Comment: Thanks, replaced with `push @charpos, [$1, $-[0]] while /([«»\n])/g;`. Not surprising, but it does not give any perfomance optimizations compared to `s///e` solution.

Comment: @ZyX: unless you are really going to be doing this a lot, efficiency is not as important as 'working' or 'maintainable'.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to find the positions of characters in a string, you can do it this way:

```
my $str = ...;
my @pos;
push @pos, pos $str while $str =~ /(?=[...])/g;
```

And then all the positions where the regex matched will be in @pos.  At least with this method you are not constantly rewriting your source string.

Comment: `pos` does not return the positions of the matches: *Returns the offset of where the last "m//g" search left off*

Comment: @Sinan => thanks, I can't remember the last time I used `pos` for anything.  Fixed with the look-ahead approach tchrist is using.

Answer (score 2):

There’s more than one way to skin a cat:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.010;
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings qw< FATAL all >;
use autodie;
use open qw< :std OUT :utf8 >;

END { close STDOUT }

my @pos = ();
my $string = q{«...«...»...«...»...»};
($string .= "\n") x= 3;

say "string is:\n$string";

for ($string) {
    push @pos, pos while m{
        (?= [«»\n] )
    }sxg;;
}
say "first  test matches \@ @pos";

@pos = ();

## this smokes :)
"ignify" while $string =~ m{
    [«»\n]
    (?{ push @pos, $-[0] })
}gx;
say "second test matches \@ @pos";

__END__
string is:
«...«...»...«...»...»
«...«...»...«...»...»
«...«...»...«...»...»

first  test matches @ 0 4 8 12 16 20 21 22 26 30 34 38 42 43 44 48 52 56 60 64 65
second test matches @ 0 4 8 12 16 20 21 22 26 30 34 38 42 43 44 48 52 56 60 64 65
```

But please credit [Sinan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249452/find-positions-of-given-characters/4249627#4249627).

Comment: A-ha! So, @Eric's answer would be correct if we assumed `(?=` inside the `[...]` ;-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A regular-expression free cat skinimization to add to the manual. Whether it is monstrous is in the eye of the beholder:

```
use List::Util q/min/;
my @targets = ('«','»',"\n");
my $x = q{«...«...»...«...»...»};
my $pos = min map { my $z = index($x,$_); $z<0?Inf:$z } @targets;
my @pos;
while ($pos < Inf) {
    push @pos, $pos;
    $pos = min map { my $z = index($x,$_,$pos+1); $z<0?Inf:$z } @targets;
}
```

Comment: Here we are doing each work three times: `min` will throw away all results except one of the characters found. It is probably better to use three `pos` arrays and then merge them. I do not think, that `index` will improve perfomance at all, especially with a 0.5-1.5 MiB (in an 8-bit encoding, multiple it with ~1.75 for UTF-8) book in `$_`.